# Python PriorityQueue: Drop the lowest N tasks

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

A [PriorityQueue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) in python allows you pop the highest priority entry first. I have a case where my queue gets filled with lower priority tasks. Once the queue reaches size N, I'd like to drop the lowest X tasks to keep my queue small. Is this possible? I'd also like to drop stale entries older than X seconds.

I've looked at the source of /usr/lib64/python2.7/Queue.py and don't see anything like this.

Comment: I think you're mixing up high and low. Also, unless you're using this for communication between threads, you should probably go with `heapq` instead of `PriorityQueue` - the `Queue` module is specifically designed for thread synchronization, and it makes a number of design decisions that are awkward or inefficient for general use.

Comment: To drop the lowest priority X tasks, you'll have to build a new priority queue with the highest priority N-X tasks. If you want to drop older tasks, you'll have to iterate over the existing priority queue, and build a new queue that excludes those old tasks.